# Rails Console Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

When I open Rails console, or sandbox for that matter, and I try and add new date, in this case, a user, I keep getting this same error.  I have tried everything to get it resolved, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.  I am using Windows, so obviously I know that is one of my first problems, but its all I have for the current moment, so I will have to make due.  Here is the error message that pops up when I try and simply enter user.new(information...)... any help would be greatly appreciated, I am pulling my hair out over here.

```
    C:\TTS\Rails\workspace\sample_app>rails console
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
    irb(main):001:0> user.new(name: "Will Wagar", email: "will@wagar.com")
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
            from (irb):1
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
            from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            from bin/rails:4:in `require'
            from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: If you don't like using windows to do development, try running ubuntu using a VM.

Comment: I am considering doing that with all the problems I am running into with this current setup, I probably should just bite the bullet and get it over with.

Comment: It is `User.new` with a uppercase `U`.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want `User.new` (note the capital U) rather than `user.new`, it's a Ruby convention that classes are capitalised.

To expand, you probably want to do it in several steps:

```
user = User.new(name: "Will Wagar", email: "will@wagar.com")
user.valid?
user.save
etc...
```

So in the first one you're creating an instance of the class `User` and assigning it to the variable `user` and then in subsequent operations, you're working with the new `user` variable you've created.

Comment: I see that now, but even when I try and see if it is valid or save it I get the same error, capitalized or not.

Comment: I've expanded my answer above to explain where I think the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I see that now, I should have mentioned in the question that I have tried it both ways, capitalized and not.  I can get a return when I try it with a capital U, but when I try and check to see if it is valid or save it, I get the same error.
irb(main):008:0> user.valid?
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
        from (irb):8
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in`start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in`console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in`'